# Why is the parameter of discard is of type unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I'm implementing a random number engine myself(No, I'm not inventing one) and want to know what should be done if the parameter is negative. So i check the code of mersenne_twister_engine and found this:

```
void discard(unsigned long long _Nskip)
{   // discard _Nskip elements
    for (; 0 < _Nskip; --_Nskip)
        (*this)();
}
```

Isn't unsigned type dangerous in these place?

Comment: Actually allowing negative values could be more dangerous...

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas I just don't want the -1 become 18446744073709551615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people like to use `unsigned` for variables that only store positive quantities. Some other people don't want to use `unsigned` to denote that meaning.

It's an often and much discussed topic. I'm in the latter camp: I won't use `unsigned` in such parameters. When I write a `size()` function for a `list`-like class for instance, I use `int`, even though a size will never become smaller than 0.

Putting an assert or test-and-throw to reject negative `int` values seems appropriate if you want. People from the `unsigned` camp will say that the compiler should warn on the call-side when you pass a negative value. You can go on with arguments and I'm sure you will find lots of them on the interwebs.

Answer (score 2):

It's only dangerous if the condition is `x <= 0`.  `x > 0` (or `0 < x`) is safe.

Basically what you must avoid is subtracting from 0 (more specifically, you need it such that `x - y >= 0`).  The for-statement will be executed one last time, and if the loop were checking for equality to 0, that would be a problem (0 - 1 typically = max).  As long as 1 is the ending condition, subtracting one from it is fine (`1 - 1 >= 0`).

Edit: Upon reading your question again, I'm not sure if I addressed the actual question (I think you may have edited within the 5 minute window? Or maybe I just failed at reading it.))

Anyway, the reason it's unsigned was alluded to by David Rodriguez: discarding a negative number of elements doesn't make sense.  (Also, if you did actually manage to  pass a negative value to that [in the form it's in], it would at that point be the bit pattern for a huge positive number, and bad, bad things would happen.)

Comment: Well, what I want is to avoid a negative value (which might be passed by accident) become a huge positive number. I thought we need to check the parameter and throw an exception if it's negative. And it seems that the standard don't care about that.